# Can I get vs Can I borrow

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

I wanted to borrow a cable from someone and said:
*"Can I get your cable?"*

I wonder if 'get' can be said instead of 'borrow' or are they used in different contexts?

Answer (score 3):

To me, as an older British person, *Can I get your cable?* would mean *May I fetch it from (wherever it is)?*. I know many younger people are using *Can I get...* when asking for something in a shop or restaurant. However, *borrow* (or *have the loan of*) is the only way of saying clearly that you will give the item back when you have finished with it.